# iOS UITabBarController best practice: one tab one controller or multiple tabs one controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS development and has started working with Swift.  I am currently using a Tab Bar Navigation which contains 3 tab/navigation.  Should I subclass the UIViewController and use it for all 3 scenes or each scene should have its own subclass of UIViewController.  What is the best practice on this?

Thank you.

## UPDATE

Thank you @Larcerax and @Adrian for the input, I have updated my storyboard as such:

[image]

Each tab navigation will have each own UINavigationController and subclass of UIViewController. Please let me know if I interpret your directions incorrectly.

Comment: that's excellent, I like it, I don't use storyboards myself, but this is exactly the set up I was talking about. one powerful reason is this: You can start your app with a regular view if you want to and then when the sign up is done and everything is set up, THEN you push the big PILE of navigation controllers onto the stack and the app is up and running

Comment: This is going to give you the ability to have a very very very dynamic app, you will be able to take total control of the code base, but it will get advanced. The good news also is that you are going to learn a ton doing it this way.

Comment: One more thing you will have to mess around with is this: You now have a few navigation controllers deep in the stack, you may need to call "setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE" if you find that your navigation bar at the top is acting screwy, other than this, you can push from the tabs, you can present from the tabs, and you can do all sorts of other neat stuff.

Comment: And yes, Andi, this is exactly what I'm talking about, you nailed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, and I've been in your shoes before, I'd not do what you are saying, but I would completely revamp the strategy and go this route:

App Delegate: MainScreenRootViewController ===> UITabBarController:

Tab 1 ====> UINavigationController ====> UIViewController

Tab 2 ====> UINavigationController ====> UIViewController

Tab 3 ====> UINavigationController ====> UIViewController

Doing it this way will give you more leeway as to what you can do later since now every tabbaritem has it's own navigation framework and the entire app has it's own navigation framework as well that will allow you more flexibility to work with additional views, and windows. Should you have additional questions, please feel free to fire away, I'll answer as many questions as I have time for.

and in fact, here's some code for you that I found:

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

        var nav1 = UINavigationController()
        var first = FirstViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        nav1.viewControllers = [first]

        var second = SecondViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        var nav2 = UINavigationController()
        nav2.viewControllers = [second]

        var tabs = UITabBarController()
        tabs.viewControllers = [nav1, nav2]

        self.window!.rootViewController = tabs;
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible();

        return true
    }
```

This is how you root the tabs with navigation controllers and then root the main window with a Tabbar controller, the only thing that I would do different is root the tabbar in a navigation controller and then root this combo as the rootViewcontroller of the window.

Answer (score 3):

Chances are you'll be doing different things on different `UIViewController`s, so you'll want to have a different view controller for each scene. As you work with `UIViewControllers`, you'll see a lot of repetition re: the methods used, but you'll probably be doing different things inside those methods on different `ViewController`s.